# can we use google drive functionality in asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

I want to use google drive functionality in my website, like user can view, download and upload their google drive content after providing login credentials using my website.

Is this functionality possible? Feel free to correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed google drive functionality in your website. For that google provides google drive api. For CMS like Joomla can  be used for embedding it into your webpage. Here is one link which lists the steps for plugging in the Google drive api into your webpage:

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1KBFyPhCbDVwT1PZG8mmjWIsB2nBMvOfoVr8_VOSIoGE/edit?pli=1#slide=id.gf0ec6a4_0_114

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Drive SDK for .NET, file-explorer could be developed which can connect Google Drive for saving and retrieving changes. Read start-up guide [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs) and try hands-on DrEdit Web Application [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet) which clearly demonstrates how to implement the same.

Comment: I have worked through the startup example which is about uploading a file on google drive. But facing problem with  DrEdit sample, mostly with URL's. Need to provide many url and i'm totally confused about it.  do you know the steps to implement DrEdit? and can it(DrEdit) be implemented on localhost?

Comment: kindly refer https://developers.google.com/drive/enable-sdk, this says localhost won't work in OpenURL. Public assessible IIS and a FQDN are required. While registering DrEdit you may be facing problems. Fresh start https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet#setting_up_this_sample_application might be helpful.